# WordPress Protected Page Password Cookie

Tags: wordpress, cookies, passwords, protected

When you login to a password protected page, WordPress sets a cookie that looks like wp-postpass_*hash*.

This cookie seems to stick around forever. I'd like to be able to provide the user with a 'log out' link. Is there a way for me to find and delete this particular cookie if I don't know the hash? Maybe there's a way to get the cookie by finding it based on 'wp-postpass'?

I've seen other solutions for altering WordPress' core files to change the expiration date of the cookie, but this won't last when there's an update. Maybe there's a function I could write to alter the expiration of this particular cookie?

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$pass_cookie='';
foreach($_COOKIE as $key=>$value){
  if(!strncmp($key,"wp-postpass_",12)){
    $pass_cookie = $key;
    break;
  }
}
if($pass_cookie){
  setcookie($pass_cookie,'',0);
}
?>
```

I would rather use something like the above - it doesn't depend on the position of the wp_postpass cookie

Answer (score 3):

That's okay if you don't know the hash. Actually cookie hash is the MD5 of the blog url. If you want to know your site cookie hash then try this:

```
<?php

    $url="http://www.your-blog.com";
    $COOKIEHASH = md5($url);

    //Now, your cookie will be,
    echo 'wp-postpass_' . $COOKIEHASH; // Name of the cookie of your blog

    //Now, you can delete it whenever you want. :)

    //setting your cookie
    //setcookie('wp-postpass_' . $COOKIEHASH, $password, time() + 864000, COOKIEPATH);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried providing the user a link to [`wp_logout_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url), instead of programming it for yourself?

Comment: wp_logout_url() is for logging out registered users. I'm referring to password protected pages, which is cookie based.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
<?php
// turn all cookies into string
$cookie_string = implode(array_keys($_COOKIE));
// find position of desired cookie
$pos = strpos($cookie_string,'wp-postpass');
// extract string starting at $pos
$pass_cookie = substr($cookie_string,$pos);
// set cookie to expire on browser close
setcookie($pass_cookie,'',0);
?>
```

This probably isn't the most elegant solution, especially because it requires the wp-postpass cookie to be last in the array.